# Можно ли получить то, что передано конструктору класса?

Tags: c#, .net

Возможно глупый вопрос, но я туплю и не могу ничего сделать. Есть следующий код:

```
 public class EventHandlers
{

    public EventHandlers( Permissions per)
    {
        per.Data = "safafs"; //Первый случай
    }

    public void safd()
    {
      //Второй случай
    }

}
```

В первом случае, очевидно, все отлично. Но вот как сделать что-то похожее во втором я, к сожалению, не знаю. Есть идеи, товарищи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подумайте сами, если вам нужен объект везде (не только в одном методе), то что надо сделать? Правильно, объявить его в классе, а не в методе. Тогда через конструктор вы можете задать ему нужные данные.

```
public class EventHandlers
{
    Permissions Permissions;
    public EventHandlers( Permissions per)
    {
        Permissions = per;
        //...
    }

    public void safd()
    {
       Permissions.Data = "safafs";
    }
}
```

Comment: я пытался подобным образом делать - не работало

Comment: Я вам уже показал как это делается. То, что вы говорите `не работало` - мне нечего не говорит. Суть тут заключается в том, что вы инициализируете где то объект (`MyClass Class1 = new MyClass();`) и если вам нужно работать с этим объектом в другом классе, то вы передаете на него ссылку при инициализации, то есть `TestClass Class2 = new TestClass(Class1);`, сам объект принимается в TestClass так, как я показал в ответе.

Comment: Действительно, моя опечатка привела к вопросу, на который я знал ответ. Все равно спасибо. Я принял ваш ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Стоит пересмотреть то что вы пытаетесь сделать. Высока вероятность работы с не корректно инициализированным классом. Есть хорошая идиома    [RAII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)  которая призвана избавить от таких  вещей. В конкретном случае можно повесить флаг на инициализацию, но это очень грязно.